# Fit element next to another one?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position a little down arrow beside a textbox.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sdVMG/)

How can I make the box fit snuggly against the input, such that their tops and bottoms align?

Must be a way to grab the position info was JS/jQuery and then... what, should I absolute-position it?

---

**Edit:** Got it [pretty darn close](http://jsfiddle.net/4WFgW/) to how I want. It's still a little off in IE8... anyway I can nudge it over?

Comment: FYI: the google's main page has the search button next to the text field the way you want.

Comment: if you type something in the search box, it displays the list of results, and at the top of the list is a text field with the button.

Comment: @akonsu: Right! Basically I want something just like that, but I want to do it JS, assuming I don't have control over how the textbox is styled.

Comment: I think I got it working actually: http://jsfiddle.net/nJpJN/ in FF anyway... how can I make it cross-browser? Doesn't look right in chrome.

Comment: @Mark, why are you so intent on using Javascript, that is like using a bone saw to remove a splinter. JS should be a last resort when browser issues prevent a pure CSS solution.

Comment: @akonsu, aha, google instant search, never paid close attention.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not something that should require JavaScript.

My first suggestion would be to try using a `button` or `input[type=button]` element instead of a span, I have always had better luck lining up text boxes with real buttons than fake ones.

Here is what I see when I convert the elements to buttons:

[image]

It is not a perfect solution, but with some minor tweaking to the button and textbox styles you should be able to make it work.

Keep in mind, different browsers use different default styles for rendering form widgets, so it can be hard coming up with a universal solution, note the difference in the textbox border.

The difference is more dramatic in your original example:

[image]

You will definately want to apply a custom style to the text box in order to get consistent and predictable results.

Comment: No, it doesn't *require* JS, but I want to use JS because I'm adding the arrow dynamically. Progressive enhancement. Still doesn't look good enough for me :\ Wish I could get it closer.

Comment: @Mark, progressive enhancement does not mean you have to do all your styling in layout.  In fact I would say that it is the most common practice.  Even with progressive enhancement, the only time a sane developer wouldn't use CSS, is when they are using absolute positioning or compensating for browser incompatibilities.

Comment: I was thinking I wouldn't have any control over how the textbox was styled, thus I would have to use JS to match at least *some* of the styling, such as the height of the box. In hindsight, most plugins get you to customize the CSS to make it pretty anyway. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
.cb-arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,
        rgb(242, 242, 242) 0%,
        rgb(221, 221, 221) 50%,
        rgb(207, 207, 207) 100%)
        repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    margin-left:-5px
}


.combobox { border:1px solid #BBB; padding:2px 2px 1px 2px; margin:0 }
```

Not the prettiest solution but will work.

//EDIT: VERSION TWO

Scrap the javascript (for now). Add a container.  Looks good in all, consistent in FF and Chrome:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  <input type="text" class="combobox" />
  <button type='button' class='cb-arrow'>&#9660;</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { height:20px;line-height:20px }

.cb-arrow {
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    background:white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:-5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.combobox { 
    border:1px solid gray; 
    border-right:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:1px
}
```

Comment: Too big in IE, too small in Chrome, just right in FF. http://jsfiddle.net/sdVMG/7/

Comment: Different versions then, I get just right in FF and Chrome, and a symmetrical overlap in IE...

Answer (score 0):

seems to work in IE and FF. i do not have chrome.

```
<style>
#container *
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container .cb-arrow
{
    height:22px;
    line-height:22px;
    width:20px;
}
#container .combobox
{ 
    border-right:0px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
}
</style>
<div id='container'>
    <input type="text" class="combobox" />
    <button type='button' class='cb-arrow'>&#9660;</button>
</div>
```